# Angular set input value to be an object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-forms

i have an input and i want to be able to have a formControl on that input that is an object in the form of:

```
{
    id:'123',
    name: 'Name'
}
```

but i want my input to display the name property of the object, right now if i set the object as the formControl value I get [object Object], how would I go about doing this?

Comment: can you add your project at https://stackblitz.com/ for easy debugging

Answer (score 0):

```
         mainFormGroup= new FormGroup({
            nameObject: new FormGroup({
                            id: ['123'], // no need to bind to html
                            name: new FormControl('') // bind it to input
                         }),
            otherProperty: new FormControl(''),
          });
```

`mainFormGroup.value` should give you the below object.

```
 {  nameObject: { id: 123 , name: ''} , otherProperty: ''}
```